# PHP openssl in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl, phpmailer

I have created a web app which uses PHPMailer for mailing and its working properly on my local server(Windows OS). However, when I uploaded it to the production server(Ubuntu 14.04.4) it returned an error which says ***“Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl”***.I tried looking for solution but nothing works. Anyway I'm using PHP5.3.6. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: try to install openssl extension

Comment: that's the problem, I tried but it didn't work. can you show me the step on how to install it and include it to PHP?

Comment: if you install php by apt before，you can try command "sudo  apt-get install php5-openssl"

Comment: Oh, I'll try to do that. Thanks for your suggestion :D

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur - it says, unable to locate package :( Any other solution?

Comment: try  `php -i | grep -i openssl` , to check whether the openssl have install before , it seems  the openssl extension is installed default

Comment: PHP 5.3 has been EOL since Aug 2014. You seriously need to upgrade for at least security's sake, if not also performance and modern language features. http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @Sammitch Even I'd loved to, I cant. The other web apps that are running in the production server is not compatible with the newer version. So this is not the right time to do that. :(

Comment: "You can pretend to care about your users and help them run old versions of software or you can actually care about them and give them incentive to upgrade. Do the responsible thing, run supported software and encourage your users to as well."

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur I cant use that command, because there is no CLI in my php. Anyway, I also checked the php.ini and I noticed that all of the extensions are uses '.dll' plus all of them are commented.

Comment: @Sammitch The thing is, the man power is not enough. I guess I have to upgrade first the existing apps in my development server before upgrading the existing version of the PHP in production server.

Anyway, the critical thing to do now is to install openssl in my php :(

Comment: if you cannot use cli ,you should check your server configure by <?php  phpinfo() ?>, the openssl seems build-in   in  php5.6 and php7.The most complicated　method is to compile the openssl extension source .

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur - openssl support disabled (install ext/openssl) . That's what the info says about openssl.

Comment: edit your php.ini and search whether have  the `extension="openssl.so"` ,if don't exist , add it to php.ini and restart the php-fpm and check the <?php phpinfo() ?> again

Comment: That's what made me so confused. The phpInfo is pointing the exact location of the php.ini, however when I opened it. It contains 'dll' extension. instead of 'so' given the fact that Im using Ubuntu.

Comment: check the <?php phpinfo() ?> again ,and before it you should conform that the configure  of   `extension_dir = "you should check  location here "` is right  in php.ini  . Finally  enter the  folder　of extension_dir and check the extension file is openssl.so or openssl.dll

Comment: In my computer (Ubuntu) , the php.ini is like that `extension_dir = "/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20160303/"
   ` and  `extension=openssl.so
`, and when i  enter the folder `/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20160303/` , the openssl file is openssl.so

Comment: I already checked, It doesn't exist.

Comment: @Erron  your  php.ini  is in windows or Ubuntu ?you should add the detail message in main body　instead of  comment.And the most important thing is that : you check  your the window's php.ini  or the ubuntu's php.ini?

Comment: its ubuntu's php.ini.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @jww Im so sorry, my bad :( . But I guess I don't need to show any code since my problem is about the PHP configuration itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can compile the  openssl extension.

**first step** :
download the php source  in the version you are using .

**then run command**:

```
tar zxvf php-yourphpversion.tar.gz
cd php-yourphpversion/ext/openssl/

#notice if you have error  "cannot find config.m4" when run phpize , you   
#should   rename the file "config0.m4" to "config.m4" by command
#"mv config0.m4 config.m4"


/usr/local/php/bin/phpize     #here is your php location have install 
                              #in my computer ,the php is location in 
                              # /usr/local/php/ so the phpize is in
                              # /usr/local/php/bin/phpize


                                             #(your php location)/bin/php-config                                        
./configure --with-openssl --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config
make
sudo make install
```

then the openssl will install  and return a `path` 
in my computer it return `/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20160303/`

**finally modify php.ini and restart php-fpm**  :

```
extension_dir = "the path return after install"   #you should add the return path here
extension=openssl.so
```

Comment: You mean I should reinstall my existing PHP?

Comment: just compile the php extension

Comment: not the full php，just compile the openssl and install it.