# Cannot download php_openssl.dll in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl, ubuntu-16.04

Before marking this question as a duplicate, please have a look at my problem.
I am trying to connect to Azure table using my connectionString which gives me the error as:

```
failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport &quot;http&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

So for this I realised that my openssl is not loaded. Following Drew's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305954/how-to-enable-https-stream-wrappers), but as expected, after uncommenting: **extension=php_openssl.dll** and running my server, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

This means that php_openssl.dll is not present in my extentions library. So as the answer suggested, I tried to download the dll but cannot find it for Ubuntu. I also tried to install openssl using

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

to which I get:

```
openssl is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu13)
```

and then I also proceeded to follow the instructions at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881834/php-openssl-in-ubuntu) but when I write the command:

```
tar zxvf php-7.0.18.tar.gz  (where my PHP version is 7.0.18)
```

I get the following error:

```
tar (child): php-7.0.18.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

I am completely stuck and cannot figure out how to locate php_openssl.dll and put it into my extensions folder 20151012 for PHP.
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated :)

Edit:

I have already mentioned above why the answer posted at [PHP openssl in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881834/php-openssl-in-ubuntu) does not work for me.

Comment: DLL files are meant for Windows operating systems only.

Comment: Dll files are windows file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP openssl in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881834/php-openssl-in-ubuntu)

Comment: use `find` command to locate `openssl.so` file and edit the php.ini appropriately. usually its the extensions directory

Comment: @thepieterdc please look at my question again (and I have already made an edit regarding is as well) why the method at your suggested duplicate of my question does not work for me.

Comment: @ShobiPP I used find to locate openssl.so, I found it at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.3.0/openssl.so location, but this doesn't look like an extensions folder for PHP. I am not sure whether to add this in my php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OpenSSL requires an external extension, its built into ubuntu's PHP, can you try removing and reinstalling PHP again? and try seeing the `phpinfo()` in browser?

[image: You should be able to see this both]

You Should be able to see both of these sections

[image: You should be able to see this both]